# Why are Open3D normals incorrect in x-direction?

Tags: python, normals, open3d

I am computing normals for a pointcloud in Open3D

Using:

```
points = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (10000, 6))

pointcloud = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pointcloud.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points[:, [0, 1, 2]])
pointcloud.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points[:, [3, 4, 5]])
pointcloud = o3d.geometry.voxel_down_sample(pointcloud, voxel_size=0.1)

print("Recompute the normal of the downsampled point cloud ...")
# Why are all the normals in the x direction positive?
o3d.geometry.estimate_normals(
    pointcloud,
    #search_param=o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamKNN(knn=250),
    search_param=o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(radius=1.0, max_nn=30)

)

print(np.round(np.asarray(pointcloud.normals).min(axis=0), 3))
print(np.round(np.asarray(pointcloud.normals).max(axis=0), 3))
```

The result is:

```
[ 0. -1. -1.]
[1. 1. 1.]
```

Why are all the x components of the normals positive?

Comment: Why wouldn't they be?

Comment: @Marcin The roof points Up towards the sky is positive z-direction. So there are faces of the roof facing north east south and west. Sl some of the normals should have a negative x component

Comment: @Marcin I get the same results if my points are `points = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (1000, 6))` which makes me think I'm missing something? Why would there be a normal with a negative x-component?

Comment: I found the reason, the normal are oriented underneath the roof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some normals were below the surface, solution was:

`o3d.geometry.orient_normals_to_align_with_direction(
    pointcloud, 
    orientation_reference=np.array([0., 0., 1.])
)`